# ¿Como paso el resultado de la query a una variable a mostrar?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Esta es la consulta, no se como pasar el resultado de la consulta a una variable para mostrar con el `return`

```
public double numHabitantes(int id) {
        double habitantes  =0;
        try {
            Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet res;
            res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT sum(Millones_habitantes) FROM pais WHERE IdContinente = " + id);

              orden.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return habitantes;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando estás trabajando con ResultSet la manera mas sencilla (en mi opinión) para extraer un valor es la siguiente:

```
Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res;
int tuVariable;
//Añadimos un alias al select sum, para poder identificarlo de manera mas sencilla
res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT sum(Millones_habitantes) AS suma_habitantes FROM pais WHERE IdContinente = " + id);

rs.next();
tuVariable = rs.getInt("suma_habitantes");
```

Hay que tener en cuenta, que si tu consulta devolviera mas de un registro, se iría sobrescribiendo el valor de la variable `tuVariable`

Una manera de recuperar varios resultados sería la siguiente, utilizar un ArrayList:

```
Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res;
ArrayList<int> tuVariable;
//Añadimos un alias al select sum, para poder identificarlo de manera mas sencilla
res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT sum(Millones_habitantes) AS suma_habitantes FROM pais WHERE IdContinente = " + id);
tuVariable = new ArrayList<int>();
while(rs.next()){
    tuVariable.add(rs.getInt("suma_habitantes"));
}
```

Comment: Mi consulta devuelve un solo dato la suma de los habitantes

Comment: @unknow edito mi respuesta para añadir mas información

Comment: Lo probare y te digo